# How would I punctuate/capitalize quotes without speaker tags?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

If I have a sentence like this:

> Statements such as "It's not a problem," or "It's no big deal" are unrealistic.

How exactly should I punctuate it?  Would I capitalize the I in "it's"? Does the comma belong in the first phrase *(It's not a problem,)*? Should there be any punctuation within the quotes that are in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: Hi Trish - Welcome to ELU! Sorry, but I'm not getting how your question relates to the heading.  What's unrealistic about those statements and where do the speaker tags enter into the equation?

Comment: That is the sentence I'm asking about. Would I capitalize the I in "it's"? Does the comma belong in the first phrase (It's not a problem,). Should there be any punctuation within quotes that are in the middle of a sentence such as the example above?

Comment: What does "without speaker tags" mean?

Comment: Hi @Trisha, I took the liberty of moving your comment into the body of the question.  Please feel free to edit the question for further clarity or to expand on any of your concerns.

Comment: @DigitalChris, I believe she is referring to the lack of things like "He said", "Bob declared", "Sue shouted" being attached to the actual quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write the sentence using American English:

> Statements such as "It's not a problem" and "It's no big deal" are unrealistic.

All I've done is remove the comma and change *or* to *and*.

I think *or* would be better if you said:

> A statement such as "It's not a problem" or "It's no big deal" is unrealistic.

In British English, I believe ' would be used instead of ".

You could also put the quoted parts in italics if you're not actually quoting a specific person, but just making a generalization:

> Statements such as *It's not a problem* and *It's no big deal* are unrealistic.